# Python arithmetic

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I am trying to understand why is it that the graph output of matplotlib looks this way,
I know that Python uses IEEE-754 float arithmetic. This might mean that any number x < 1 would never reach 1 as we apply sqrt to it 128 times, as it would simply keep adding trailling 9's until the mantissa digits for it "run out". But then, what's so special about the number 128?
Thanks in advance.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def sqrt_128(x):
    for _ in range(128):
        x = np.sqrt(x)
    return x

def square_128(y):
    for _ in range(128):
        y = np.power(y, 2)
    return y

x = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
plt.plot(x, square_128(sqrt_128(x)))
```

[Matplotlib output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1i8k.png)

Comment: I don't understand your concept of "special"; you found a convoluted way to determine the precision cataclysm point, but there's nothing particularly "magic" here.

Comment: Re “Python uses IEEE-754 float arithmetic”: The Python documentation does not specify this; it leaves floating-point up to each implementation. Many use IEEE-754 to some extent but have deviations from it.

Comment: @Prune I simply want to explain why this _is_ the cataclysm point.

Comment: There's nothing special about the number `128` in this context. You'll see the same graph with `128` replaced with `64`, or `256,` or `79`, or `379`, or a whole range of other numbers.